# NullReferenceException for placeholders in Experience Editor

Tags: sxa, placeholders

I am facing an issue with Experience Editor. Each placeholder is throwing null reference exception.

e.g. `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("body-top")`

I tried removing this placeholder but it will throw same exception on the next one. This keeps happening.

```
Error Rendering View: /Views/DemoSiteLayout/DemoSiteLayout.cshtml:
Error while rendering view:
'/Views/DemoSiteLayout/DemoSiteLayout.cshtml' (model:
'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').    at
Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)    at
 Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) Inner
Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at
 Sitecore.XA.Foundation.PlaceholderSettings.Services.LayoutsPageContext.GetLayout(String
layout)    at
 Sitecore.XA.Foundation.PlaceholderSettings.Services.LayoutsPageContext.GetSxaPlaceholderItems(String
 layout, String placeholderKey, Item currentItem, ID deviceId)    at
 Sitecore.XA.Foundation.PlaceholderSettings.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.GetAllowedRenderings.Process(GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs
args)    at (Object , Object )    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)   
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
 Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Editing.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetPlaceholderChromeData.Process(GetChromeDataArgs
args)    at (Object , Object )    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)   
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.GetChromeData.GetChromeDataPipeline.Run(GetChromeDataArgs
 args)    at
 Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.PlaceholderMarker.GetClientData()
at
Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.PlaceholderMarker.get_ClientData()
at
 Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.PlaceholderMarker.GetStart()
 at Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Presentation.Wrapper..ctor(TextWriter
writer, IMarker marker)    at
Sitecore.Mvc.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.AddWrapper.Process(RenderPlaceholderArgs
args)    at (Object , Object )    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)    at
Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)   
at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String
pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)    at
Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String
pipelineName, TArgs args)    at
Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String
placeholderName, TextWriter writer)    at
Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String
placeholderName)    at
ASP._Page_Views_SxaLayout_DemoSiteGridBody_cshtml.Execute() in
 c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite.local\Views\SxaLayout\DemoSiteGridBody.cshtml:line
7    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)    at
 Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.RazorService.GetRazorViewAsString(Object
model, String filePath)    at
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Grid.Extensions.GridExtensions.GridBody(RazorExtensions
 helper)    at
 ASP._Page_Views_DemoSiteLayout_DemoSiteLayout_cshtml.Execute() in
 c:\inetpub\wwwroot\DemoSite.local\Views\DemoSiteLayout\DemoSiteLayout.cshtml:line
 52    at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
 System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
 System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
 pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)    at
System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)   
at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

Page works fine in front end though.

**Update:** This error just helped me find out where the problem is (at placeholder) but doesn't seems to be very informative.

Comment: I have faced this issue. But in my case, I have missed adding the null check in my cod.so if anything is wrong in the code and didn't catch it in the try block definitely it will throw the error in the placeholder line. Please check your error log.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see the `Error rendering view` message, I've found checking the Inner exception part of the error message helps a lot to find the root cause of the error.

So, as per the error info you've shared, in your case the Null Reference exception is happening at the following code i.e., `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.PlaceholderSettings.Services.LayoutsPageContext.GetLayout(String layout)`. See below,

```
Inner Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 **at
 Sitecore.XA.Foundation.PlaceholderSettings.Services.LayoutsPageContext.GetLayout(String
 layout) at ..**
```

A string type variable (named **layout**) is passed to this method `LayoutsPageContext.GetLayout(String layout)`. So, this layout string variable should have been a NULL value while it was passed to the method.

You may have to check if anything is wrong with the layout